# C++ 'Runtime error time: 0 memory: 3452 signal:11'

Tags: c++, runtime

I'm new to programming in C++ and I'm working on a project.

One of the core function should check an array in order to find if it's compatible within N sigma to other arrays contained in a matrix, i post the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void confronto(double*, double**, double**, double*, int*, int, int, int*);

double rnd(){return double(rand())/RAND_MAX;};

/*argomenti funzione, in ordine:
spettro misurato, database dei picchi, database delle dev. std, vettore dove 
metteremo tutti gli errori sulle parole, un vettore di 1 della stessa lunghezza 

delle parole (lo uso come booleano),
#parole, #campioni delle parole, classifica delle parole papabili

La funzione NON RITORNA VALORI, ma agisce direttamente su vettori e valori 

passati
dal programma. dovendo agire su vettori mi è sembrata la cosa più comoda.
Oltre agli input quindi le uniche var che ci interessano di più sono best ed 

err:
la prima è un vettore che restituisce gli indici corrispondenti alle parole che
hanno passato il test delle N deviazioni standard in ordine crescente di errore.
La seconda ci fornisce per ogni parola l'errore associato in unità arbitrarie, 
che può essere usato come stima della bontà della identificazione.*/
void confronto(double *spettro, double* datab[5], double* datasig[5], double err[], 
                                int accettabile[], int nwords, int size, int best[]){
    //numero max dev std
    int N= 2;
    //numero max picchi "ciccati"
    int failmax = 2;
    //contatore per i fallimenti
    int fail;


    for (int i =0; i<nwords; i++){
        fail = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<size; j++){
            err[i]+= abs(spettro[j] - datab[i][j]);
            if((abs(spettro[j]-datab[i][j])/datasig[i][j])>N){
                fail++;
                if(fail>failmax){accettabile[i]=0;};
            };
        };

    };

    //i prossimi due double sono "segnaposto" per ordinare il vettore degli 
//errori
    //e tener conto dell'indice corrispondente
    double temperr = 0;
    double tempind = 0;
    for (int i =0; i<nwords; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<nwords; j++){
            //se ho superato i fallimenti concessi, IGNORO la 

//potenziale parola
            if (accettabile[i]==1){
                 if(err[j] < err[i]){

                       temperr = err[i];
                       err[i] = err[j];
                       err[j] = temperr;
                       best[i]=j;

                 };
            };
        };
    };
};






int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int nwords=3;
    int size = 5;
    double spettro[size];
    double datab [nwords] [size];
    double datasig [nwords] [size];
    double err[nwords] = {0};
    int accettabile[nwords];
    for (int i = 0; i<nwords; i++){accettabile[i] = 1;};
    int best[nwords] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i<nwords; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<size;j++){
        datab[i][j] = j + rnd();
        datasig[i][j] = (rnd() + rnd())/3.;

        };

    };  
    for (int i = 0; i<size;i++){spettro[i] = i+(2*rand() -1);};
    double *tmpdb = (double*)datab;
    double *tmpsig = (double*)datasig;
    confronto(spettro,&tmpdb,&tmpsig,err,accettabile,nwords,size,best);
    //  cout<< "migliori risultati e errori corrispondenti" << endl;
    //for (int i = 0; i<nwords; i++){
    //  if(best[i]!=0){
    //  cout << best[i] << "   " << err[i] << endl;};
    //};



return 0;

}
```

Whenever I run the code (on Ideone.com, due to some problems to my PC I'm unable to compile on any local IDE), I get the mentioned error. I tried to google it but didn't find any solution to my problem.

I know the code is probably suboptimal in terms of performance, but the whole project is not that heavy so I'm not looking for optimization.

Comment: what is the error? I can't see it in your post.

Comment: you have to learn to use a debugger

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing 2D array by value doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239203/passing-2d-array-by-value-doesnt-work) : I think that you've defined your 2d arrays as double[x][5]. If so,  the parameter passing that you use will cause the compiler to look for elements at the wrong place corrupting memory and triggering this segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work when you pass a 2d array into function. I made a change on your code on following places.

First, change the definition of the function as

```
void confronto(double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int, int, int*);
```

Call the function as the old way

```
double *tmpdb = (double*)datab;
double *tmpsig = (double*)datasig;
confronto(spettro, tmpdb, tmpsig, err, accettabile, nwords, size, best);
```

In this way, the 2d array is unrolled as a 1d array and passed into the function, so in the function, you should use the array as following way:

```
err[i] += abs(spettro[j] - datab[i*size+j]);
if ((abs(spettro[j] - datab[i*size+j]) / datasig[i*size+j])>N){
```

After applying above changes, it works well on my computer.